# Parsing Json from Api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having this type of response from API

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 539,
            "user_id": 3115,
            "amount": 5788,
            "payment_gateway": "bank",
            "message": "chchhb",
            "status": "waiting",
            "source": "everyone",
            "created_ts": "2019-12-19 13:41:17",
            "processed_ts": null
        },
      ]
}
```

this is my model.dart

```
class Model {
  final String status;
  final List<String> data;

  Model({
    this.status,
    this.data
  });

  factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    var data  = parsedJson['data'];
     List<String> dataList = data.cast<String>();
    return Model(
      status: parsedJson['status'],
      data: dataList
    );
  }

}
```

This is how I am fetching data from the model

```
 Future<List<String>> getWithdrawals() async {
      final userModel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);
      var userId = userModel.user.id;
      Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {'Content-type': 'application/json'};
      var body = {
        'id': userId,
      };
      final response = await http.post(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200){
        var jsonresponse = json.decode(response.body);
        var withdrawals = WithdrawalModel.fromJson(jsonresponse);
        return withdrawals.data;
      } else {
        print("Error" + response.body);
        return null;
      }
    }
```

I am not able to display the data on the screen It is giving me an error like

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in typecast
```

In `FutureBuilder<List>` I am not able to get data
I don't know where I am doing a mistake Please help...

Comment: Show your FutureBuilder widget

Comment: Tools like [This](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) or [This](https://app.quicktype.io/), would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My model was incorrect.
Solved by this model...

```
class WithdrawalModel {
  final String status;
  final String amount;
  final List<Data> data;

  WithdrawalModel({
    this.status,
    this.amount,
    this.data
  });

  factory WithdrawalModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    var list  = parsedJson['data'] as List;
    List<Data> dataList = list.map((i) => Data.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return WithdrawalModel(
      status: parsedJson['status'],
      amount: parsedJson['amount'],
      data: dataList
    );
  }
}

class Data {
  int id;
  int amount;
  String message;
  String status;
  String source;
  String createdTs;

  Data({
    this.id,
    this.amount,
    this.message,
    this.status,
    this.source,
    this.createdTs
  });

    Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    amount = json['amount'];
    message = json['message'];
    status = json['status'];
    source = json['source'];
    createdTs = json['created_ts'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your response type is not correct currently it's `List<String>` but it should be like `List<Details>` and you need to create another model class named `Details` (Or you can change the name).
You just put your response [here](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/). It will generate dart class models for you.

NOTE: you have to remove extra comma from your response to use model generator then your response will be like.

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 539,
            "user_id": 3115,
            "amount": 5788,
            "payment_gateway": "bank",
            "message": "chchhb",
            "status": "waiting",
            "source": "everyone",
            "created_ts": "2019-12-19 13:41:17",
            "processed_ts": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit:

For example in your above model just change List type string to Details(Model) and vise-versa  :

```
class Model {
  final String status;
  final List<Details> data; // Update string with model

}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: I am not getting how to figure it out can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
Future <PaymentReply> getPayment() async {
  final userModel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);
  var userId = userModel.user.id;
  try {
    final response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"
      },
      body: '{\'id\':\''+ userId+'\'}', // You are not sending body in your code so check if it needs to be sent.
    );
    print(response.body); //CHECK IF THIS IS CORRECT RESPONSE AS EXPECTED
    PaymentReply reply =  paymentReplyFromJson(response.body);
    return reply;
  }on Exception catch (e){
    print(e);
    return PaymentReply();
  }
}
```

with my modal

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final paymentReply = paymentReplyFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

PaymentReply paymentReplyFromJson(String str) => PaymentReply.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String paymentReplyToJson(PaymentReply data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class PaymentReply {
    int success;
    List<Datum> data;

    PaymentReply({
        this.success,
        this.data,
    });

    factory PaymentReply.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PaymentReply(
        success: json["success"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    int id;
    int userId;
    int amount;
    String paymentGateway;
    String message;
    String status;
    String source;
    String createdTs;
    String processedTs;

    Datum({
        this.id,
        this.userId,
        this.amount,
        this.paymentGateway,
        this.message,
        this.status,
        this.source,
        this.createdTs,
        this.processedTs,
    });

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        userId: json["user_id"],
        amount: json["amount"],
        paymentGateway: json["payment_gateway"],
        message: json["message"],
        status: json["status"],
        source: json["source"],
        createdTs: json["created_ts"],
        processedTs: json["processed_ts"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "user_id": userId,
        "amount": amount,
        "payment_gateway": paymentGateway,
        "message": message,
        "status": status,
        "source": source,
        "created_ts": createdTs,
        "processed_ts": processedTs,
    };
}
```

Comment: It was the typing mistake @Dev